# Searching pacman for maintainer of package

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

I'm using Arch Linux on a Rasberry Pi.
I've noticed I'm using several pacman packages that are unique to the platform and someone had gone through the trouble of repackaging popular software so it will run on the rasberry pi.

How can I on a separate machine, look up and investigate who maintains these package dialects?

For example this [documentation](https://docs.pikvm.org/tailscale/#for-each-device-you-wish-to-access-pikvm) page for the pikvm project mentions installing `pacman -Syu tailscale-pikvm` and this package is not found on the arch package page.

[image]

**Where can I find information about the `tailscale-pikvm` pacman package?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [FAQ of the PiKVM project](https://docs.pikvm.org/faq/#common-questions) you will be informed that

> **Is PiKVM OS its own custom distro?**
>
> No. PiKVM OS is an [Arch Linux ARM](https://archlinuxarm.org/) with our own repository for KVM-related packages. We distribute OS images (that is, our Arch Linux ARM build) to simplify installation, since PiKVM requires some tuning of the OS and special partitioning of the memory card.

If you run `pacman -Sii tailscale-pikvm` and cross-reference your `/etc/pacman.conf` you should find out from what custom package repository the package comes from.

The `PKGBUILD` files for this repository are [available on GitHub](https://github.com/pikvm/packages).